# Is an email address ending in a digit ever valid? e.g. dog@my.house39

Tags: email, smtp

Is an email valid if it ends with a digit ?  e.g.

`cat@cool.thing89`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the knowledge that an email consists of [local section]@[domain section]...

> An unbracketed domain consists of labels separated by periods and less than 253 characters.
>
> Labels can be quoted or unquoted (unquoted labels must consist of `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or any of !#$%&'*+-/=?^_{|}~` or ` and have at least one character)
>
> The right-most label must be all alphabetic.

...it is not possible for an email to end in a digit, as the domain must either be bracketed (surrounded with []) or end with an all alphabetic label or one that ends with a quote. Also, here's the relevant RFC:

> The top level domain must be all alphabetic. (RFC 3696, section 2)

Taken from [here](http://rumkin.com/software/email/rules.php).

Comment: AFAIK There is no such rule that top level domain must be all alphabetic. There is only rule that that essentially requires that top-level domain names not be all-
   numeric. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3696#section-2 Some TLD's contain digits as ascii equivalent for non ascii characters (chinese) although no TLD (currently) ends with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid, until the day that a TLD ending in a digit is created.

But I'm at a loss for the thought process behind the question. Do you really need code that rejects A@B.C1 but accepts A@B.C?

Comment: yes, I need code that does that.  Generally speaking, there are so many top level domains coming out e.g. .horse , .blue I was wondering if numbers are also allowed now.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for a solution to this question.

Top levels domains does not have numbers.

You can use a regex expression to test user input email.

Try this regex using test() method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test:

```
const regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,2}$/;

if regex.test(email) {
   // do something or just empty return
} 
else {
   // thrown an error indicating the user that he typed an invalid email format.
}
```